# Is there a way to programmatically pause Tomcat from listening to http port

Tags: java, tomcat

When a Tomcat application server starts, i need to make sure all other interfacing device is online before listening to the incoming HTTP request. Is there a way to do so programatically from java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wait is short, then I would try using a Filter. See
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html
You can check your interfacing devices in it's init method. You do't need to do anything in it's  doFilter method.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This will not work for this case because the dependency system "may" be unreachable for more than an hour. and due to SLA, our system cannot be online for that period.

Comment: During the down time, what do you want to happen when a user browses to your wep app ? 404 Not Found error message ?

Comment: I would use Tomcat's Manager app along with my Filter idea. The Filter could set a flag and start a TimerTask. When the the system is ready, the Manager can request that your application reload itself. Meanwhile your app can give friendly wait message. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Comment: Maybe the simplest way would be to have a conditional Filter. Put the logic in the doFilter method. You could redirect to wait message if the system is not ready.

Comment: After all the try, filter seems most simple and yah, i used your idea and it works as per expected. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to set the size of the thread pool associated with the http connector to zero (minSpareThreads) and then use JMX to set it to a higher value.

Just a theory - not sure if it will work.

Another option would be to explore extending the connectors with an ability to start / stop via JMX.

This post also outlines how to stop / start a connector using JMX.
http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=169

Comment: Thank you for the great idea. I am trying on them immediately!

Comment: The code execute fine and able to find the MBeanServer. Strangely, the server still able to listen to port 9090 from another browser even after the line: mbeanServer.invoke(objectName, "stop", null, null);

Comment: I am able to achieve this form jconsole. Navigate to this object - "Catalina:type=Connector,port=8080" and invoke stop.  Once I do that I can't connect to 8080 using telnet.

Comment: Yes, i am able to stop the connector from from jConsole as well. however, the code is not working as it should. i was wondering, is it because i place this code immediately during server start up?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TestFilter implements Filter {
  public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException{
                     System.out.println("init of TestFilter");
                     // Make sure all other interfacing device is online here.
  }
  public void destroy(){}        
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse resp,FilterChain chain)
     throws ServletException, IOException {   
                     chain.doFilter(req,resp);
  }
}
```